# Лицензирование по сети

Tags: delphi, сеть, лицензирование

Есть программа (десктоп, Windows), которая будет защищена лицензией. Я получаю от пользователя ключ, который генерирует программа, и регистрирую его в БД. После регистрации программа соединяется с сервером и получает лицензию.

Хотелось бы узнать, есть ли готовые решения для этого, и, если нет, то на какой технологии реализовать (язык и др.). Программа написана на Delphi. Ну, в общем, интересует технология регистрации по сети интернет. Поделитесь соображениями. Предполагается, что сервер будет арендован

Comment: самое простое - использовать http. Клиент оправляет post запрос, в тело которого включает ключ и другую полезную информацию. Сервер, обработав запрос, назад отправляет лицензию. Для клиента есть куча компонент, тот же idHttp. Сервер можно написать на чем угодно, думаю, самое простое это apache+php.

Comment: со стороны клиента понятно. меня больше интересует сторона сервера. а нет ли уже готовых решений ?

Comment: готовые решения я думаю можно найти, но обычно такие решения стоят кучу денег (неоправданно) и я не вижу проблем написать свое, которое будет отдавать правильные ответы и правильные лицензии. В принципе десяток строк на php. Но при желании можно и на делфи сделать сервер.

Comment: В таком случае дилетантский вопрос. Если будет сервис написанный на Delphi на каком хостинге и как его разместить ?

Comment: В принципе, на любом хостинге с виндой. Но они обычно дороже.

Comment: Интересная статья на эту тему https://habrahabr.ru/post/123908/, хотя и не всё объясняет. Еще порекомендую http://rsdn.ru/forum/shareware это форум программистов, специализирующихся на продаже продуктов через интернет.

Comment: Если серьёзное приложение, можно рассматривать StarForce (http://www.star-force.com/solutions/software-protection/). А так есть http://av-soft.com/ AvLock еще...